# I want iterate through the for loop to return three points

Tags: python

```
points = array

def get_nearest_point(x, y, n_points):

    dist = []
    val = []
    j = (x, y)
    for z in range(n_points):
        for i in range(len(points)):
            dist += [Distance(points[i][0],points[i][1],x,y)]
            a = dist.index(min(dist))
        val.append(points[a])
        dist.remove(min(dist))
        return val
```

Output :

get_nearest_point(50, 50,3)

[[54, 57]]

I want return something like [[54,57],[56,78],[78,90]]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is essentially find the indices of the smallest 3 elements in the given array. You can easily do this with [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) method

Anyways here is your code with numpy :

```
import numpy as np

def get_nearest_point(x, y, n):

    dist = [Distance(point[0], point[1], x, y) for point in points]
    indices = np.argsort(dist)
    return [points[i] for i in indices[:n]]
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the site!

The issue with your code as written is that the return statement is inside the loop- instead, move it outside. That way you append all three values to `val` before you return it.

Comment: Maybe so, but I still find it useful to answer the question as asked, especially for a new question asker.

Answer (score 0):

Here we calculate distance for every point, sort it by distance and get first n points.

```
def get_nearest_point(x, y, n_points):
    points_with_dist = []  # store here pairs (dist, point)
    for point in points:
        points_with_dist.append((
            Distance(point[0], point[1], x, y),
            point
        ))
    result_with_dist = sorted(points_with_dist, key=lambda struct: struct[0])[:n_points]
    result = [p[1] for p in result_with_dist]  # we need only points
    return result
```